# Python - Erro ao introduzir dado STR em dado FLOAT ou INT

Tags: python

Estou agora a iniciar a minha aprendizagem em Python e gostava de saber se existe alguma maneira de, ao introduzir um valor de texto num `input` de tipo `float` ou `string`, criar uma condição que diga que é necessário introduzir um número.
Criei um exemplo muito básico para demonstração:

```
a = float(input("introduza o primeiro número: \n"))
b = float(input("introduza o segundo número: \n"))

if a > b:
    print(f"O número {a} é maior que o número {b} .")
elif a == b:
    print(f"O número {a} é igual ao número {b} .")

else:
     print(f"O número {b} é maior que o número {a} .")
```

Se o usuário introduzir uma letra dará um erro na consola do Python mas gostaria de informar também o usuário que não pode colocar uma letra e que o valor terá de ser um número!

Ficava agradecido pela ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pode fazer por condição `try-catch`:

```
try:
    numeroInteiro = int(input("Insira um numero inteiro: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Você deve inserir um valor inteiro!")
```

Como também pode fazer por `isinstance()`

```
if(isinstance(numeroInteiro, int) == false):
    print("Você deve inserir um valor inteiro!")
```